# NodeJS - MongoClient.Connect with URL to DB Other Than Default

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'd like to use the MongoClient.Connect(Url) option for connecting from Node and in fact it does work for authenticated connections to the admin database.  However, if I try to specify a different database I get an "auth Fails" with code 18.

I think this means that the credentials are only setup on the admin database and, unfortunately, I can't change this arrangement (for now, anyway).

It seems this Url syntax is the direction the driver is heading, so I'd like to use it if possible.  Is there a way to use this syntax, authenticate and connect to the admin database, and then get a connection to one of the other databases on the server?

Answer (score 1):

I just found out how to do this: You use the instance you get ("admin") to open another database you have access to:

```
db2 = db.db("name of other name");
```

See it hidden inside [the documentation](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/db.html#id1)